# Fit html elements in least amount of height, while maintaining left-right positioning

Tags: html, css

Say I have 3 divs, each with a width of 3, a height of 1, and a left position. I do **not** know their y-positions before rendering them.

```
[a] - left 0
[b] - left 1
[c] - left 5
```

I want the divs to position themselves in this configuration:

```
 0123456789
0[a]  [c]
1 [b]
```

Say I add another div:

```
[d] - left 3

 0123456789
0[a]  [c]
1 [b]
2   [d]
```

Adding one more:

```
[e] - left 4


 0123456789
0[a]  [c]
1 [b][e]
2   [d]
```

As you can see, the divs are using the minimal amount of space in the y-direction without overlapping one another, and respecting their x-positions. What is a good way to do this without knowing the div y-positions beforehand?

Here's what my html looks like so far:

```
<div style="background:brown;height:100px;width:100px;">
      left 0
    </div>
    <div style="background:red;left:500px;height:100px;width:100px;">
      left 500
    </div>
    <div style="background:orange;left:100px;height:100px;width:100px;">
      left 100
    </div>
```

Here's a JS Bin to fiddle around with: 
http://jsbin.com/linejagitu/edit?html,output

Thanks!

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: Can you post a graphical representation of what you have VS what you want? I'm not understanding just by looking at your [0]'s. (Is that [1] supposed to be equally between the [0] and [2] but on a new line?)

Comment: Okay, I added a few more examples as well as some html. Is what I'm trying to do clear enough? Or would you like different/more examples? Thanks again!

Comment: are you at all interested in using a responsive, grid-based framework for this type of layout?  It seems like a good fit for what you are trying to do

Comment: You could use a grid framework like http://isotope.metafizzy.co/layout-modes.html ...check out the "Fit Columns" layout.

Comment: I'm using reactjs to build my layout so I'm doubtful that a grid-framework would work for me. I'd definitely prefer a mixture of pure html styles to solve it.